# What would be the options to supply a 3-phase motor without using the power lines?

Tags: induction-motor, vfd

If we have a 3-phase 600A, 400V AC induction motor with a VFD.
Are there any techniques to supply it with a huge acu/battery or a generator.
This is to use when electricity is gone or no power network grid around.
Any ideas or examples from industry?

Comment: You can certainly get 3-phase generators and UPS systems, although they're not cheap.

Comment: The Tesla car proves its basically feasible.

Comment: A VFD (Variable frequency drive) uses a DC link between the converter and inverter stages, so you would just need the batteries, possibly a DC Link voltage controller, and an inverter.

Comment: there is vfd. where can i find the batteries for dc link and the dc link controller?

Comment: @user16307 http://www.bonitron.com/m3460.html We make exactly what you're looking for. Email us or give us a call!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to supply a VFD during an outage. Which makes the most sense depends on the details of your application. In particular, how long do you need to run during a power outage?

If you need to survive an indefinite-duration outage, you need a generator, period. Any generator should be fine, though you'll need to size it to account for the harmonic content of the VFD. You also won't be able to use line-regenerative braking unless there are other loads on the generator to consume the energy.

Now, if you need to run off the generator exclusively, and never have a power line, you're done. If, however, you need to be able to switch between the power grid and a generator, you have more issues to account for. All generators have a spin-up time long enough that the VFD will trip out before it can switch over. So you need an supply for during that changeover. That's got to be batteries or capacitors, and probably a voltage regulator of some kind.

There are two basic approaches here. One is a UPS of some kind, which puts out AC. You can get a double-conversion UPS, which sources the load all the time. Or you can get a multimode UPS, where your load is sourced from the power grid until there's a disturbance, at which point the UPS switches in to take over.

If all you're backing up is a VFD, however, a UPS is not the best solution. Most VFDs (especially at the power scale you're talking about) have terminals to accept a DC input. A battery string with a voltage regulator can feed DC power into those terminals. This allows for completely bumpless transfer, fewer components, and higher standby efficiency. It's also a completely parallel solution, which is inherently more reliable.

My company makes systems like this, including storage, chargers, and regulators. We can support any power range you need, for any duration required. Contact us at www.bonitron.com and we'll help you out.

(As a footnote, there are cases where batteries aren't the preferred storage mechanism. High voltages, high powers, and short outage durations lend more towards ultracapacitors. For very low energy requirements, simple electrolytic capacitors may be appropriate. For cases where energy-efficient braking and outage ridethru are both required, a bank of ultracaps directly on the bus with no intermediate regulator may be most appropriate. There are a lot of possible variations!)

Answer (score 0):

A VFD does not need a DC link controller, it does its own voltage and current regulation. Depending on the charging current limiting control in the VFD, you may need to add a charging current limiter if you use batteries. That could be a series resistor that is shorted out after the batteries have been initially charged.

You find batteries wherever batteries are sold. You need to build a bank of batteries that can supply the required voltage, current and storage capacity. They also need to be suitable for whatever charging and discharging cycle duty you want considering the battery life that is acceptable and the cost.

Examples from industry

There are various situations in which power outage ride-thru is required. Depending on the power level and ride-thru time, either engine-generator sets or energy storage may be used. As an alternative to batteries, rotating inertia has been used. Inductive or capacitive energy storage is another alternative, but that is suitable only to provide enough time to switch to an alternative feed or execute an orderly shutdown. VFDs contain enough capacitive energy storage to meet their own orderly shutdown requirements. Sometimes that is enough to meet external shutdown or transfer requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Using batteries for a 600A (assuming 400kW?) motor for any length of time is not likely practical, but you can use batteries to "ride through" the time it takes for an Automatic Transfer Switch to detect the grid loss, start the generator, wait for it to stabilize and transfer power. On something this big, that likely would be at least 2 minutes, so to be safe, I'd say 5 minutes.

The battery voltage must be at the DC bus voltage level, so if the VFD is 400V your terminal battery voltage must be at least 564VDC. Using 12V cells, that equates to 47 in a series string. Then to provide 600A for lets say 5 minutes, you are looking at roughly 50Amp-Hrs of capacity, which is doable. But think of 47 batteries in a rack, it's going to be big and need constant maintenance. If you use Li or some other type of battery technology, the cost for that much power becomes considerable. You have to really want it. What most people do is to just let the VFD shut down during transition and restart it after the generator comes on line.